# JNI_CreateJavaVM stack corruption?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, stack

Debugging a c project that is attempting to call some java functions in a jar by using JNI_CreateJavaVM(), GetStaticMethod(), CallStaticVoidMethod() etc.
Using -> openJdk 1.6.045.

I wrote a small test program that looks similar to this:
[Sample program calling Java from C](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/c.html)

Which works.

The problem comes when I integrate this with a lot of other code. The other code crashes shortly after JNI_CreateJavaVM() - (the other code works fine otherwise).  It seems that JNI_CreateJavaVM() messes with the stack.
If I set the JavaVM up like so:

```
JavaVMOption options[2];
// Adjust stacksize.
options.[0].optionString = "path/to/class";
options.[1].optionString = "-Xss65536k";
vm_args.nOptions = 2;
vm_args.options = options;
int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **) &jenv, &vm_args);
```

Then the C program continues on happily, otherwise, if I omit the "-Xss" option, the C program terminates when it attempts to access the stack.

Any clues as to what is really going on?  I suspect stack corruption, but I'd like to be able be certain as to what is happening.

Comment: Is it crashing for any values of Xss or is it crashing with larger values? Please check with -Xss256K for 32 bit system -Xss512K for 64 bit system.

Comment: It works _with_ -Xss65536k .  If I initialize the VM without that option it crashes.

Comment: run java  -verbose:init  -version and provide the output of the verbose without -Xss option

Comment: java version "1.6.0_45"

Comment: run with this java -verbose:init -version command. I need verbose output during  VM initialization without -Xss option in place.

Comment: No time to check currently but JNI_CreateJavaVM might not create its own copy of the vm options. It might crash as soon as your "options" variable goes out of scope. Try allocating "options" with malloc.